cloudflare worker give me endless redirect issue
I am trying to learn cloudflare worker, the simple idea was that I want to cache my site's response in cloudflare cache and only access the site is the cache is empty.
However, I got too many redirect issue with my cloudflare worker code, so I crated this barebone code to demo the problem.
What I am doing wrong there?
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.passThroughOnException()
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  
  const response = await fetch(request);
  return response;
}

